# Angular filter return html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to use unsafe-html in **angularjs 1.2**. Whereas the filter without html does work, with html it does not. What I do:

I added angular-sanitize to my html head:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

My angular module:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
    .filter('convertState', function ($sce) {
        return function (state) {
            if (state == 1) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml("<strong>" + state + "</strong> special state");
            }
            else {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml("<strong>"+state + "</strong> normal state");
            }
        }
    });
```

My Html:

```
<td><span ng-bind-html="f.state | convertstate"></span></td>
```

edit: updated `ng-bind-html-unsafe` to `ng-bind-html`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been removed in Angular 1.2. Since you are correctly sanitizing your input, you should just use `ng-bind-html`.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/0bHeXrarRP7IAciqAYgM?p=preview

Comment: @zoidbergi Could you please point out the problem here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0bHeXrarRP7IAciqAYgM?p=preview It seems to work.

Comment: turned out it was a case sensitive typo! Nevertheless your answer was another problem I had. Thanks!

Comment: When using `ngSanitize` there is not always necessary to use `$sce.trustAsXXX()` (and indeed it isn't in this case). That's the whole purpose of sanitization.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like

```
app.directive('toHtml', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      el.html(scope.$eval(attrs.toHtml));
    }
  };
});
```

Use as:

```
<p to-html="name | convertState"></p>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Av2rmeXp7phkDdbYUbxF