# Angular Filters: replace model value with HTML-String

Tags: html, angularjs, filter, render

If some value in the model not set, I want to replace it with an error-text-message (see controller below, `foo` is `null`)

```
{{ foo | ifnotSet }}
```

`foo` should be replaced now in the view with

```
<span class='text-danger'>NOT SET</span>
```

How can I do that? (Without `ng-bind-html` and Co..). If I do the following (see filter) it will be replaced but not rendered as HTML.

**Controller (excerpt)**

```
$scope.foo = null;
```

**Filter**

```
.filter ("ifNotSet", function () {

    return function (input) {
        input = input || "<span class='text-danger'>NOT SET</span>";
        return input;
    }

})
```

**Important:** I would like to do it within curly brackets, if possible:

Comment: We need more information. what exactly you need ? IN && OUT

Comment: Actually, additional information is not required, the question is clear enough, but still: I can complement them with pleasure. Please see my revision in couple of minutes.

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284965/angular-filter-return-html ?

Comment: Yes I saw it but it is with `ng-bind-html`. I want to replace mass of text in existing views.  I want to find `}}` and replace it with `| myFilter }}`