# Bold an AngularJS html text without using DOM selectors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am writing a custom AngularJS filter to use in front-end to bold the text elements. As a generic filter, I do not want to tie it to specific elements, so `document.getElementsBy` is not a solution. To my understanding, i need to:

- get the input text and bold it;
- return the changed value in place and make it rendered,

The question is what possibilities do I have to get it done? I do not have an element to use `element.innerHTML = content;`. How can I get the element dynamically to later on apend it?

My filter:

```
angular.module('TestModule')
    .filter('bold', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
        return function (input) {
            console.log(input.bold());
            // code

            return input.bold();
        };
    }]);
```

in html:

```
<div>{{ person.name|bold }}</div>
```

I get `<b>Test1</b>` in front, instead of having the bolded text. An advice in which direction should I move is appreciated.

Comment: You're sure you would not be better off using ng-class?

Comment: Dead sure.This application is made for study purposes. Making it through css, inline styling, getElementBy in js, or ng-class would be too easy :)

Comment: maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284965/angular-filter-return-html

Comment: Thanks Miri, it's virtually the same that I have already applied, indeed a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `$sce.trustAsHtml` and `ng-bind-html` to accomplish this:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.word = "Test";
  })

  .filter("bold", ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(`<b>${val}</b>`);
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    Word : {{ word }}<br/> Bold Word: <span ng-bind-html="word | bold"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this one is best suiting my needs and now everything works as charm!

Answer (score 1):

The return value is string-raw-value. you should change the value into html.such as the ng-bind-html and ng-bind.

Comment: But these are impossible to use with <div>{{ person.name|bold }}</div>, right?

Comment: this belongs to the comments section I think

Comment: <div ng-bind-htm= 'person.name | bold'></div>